# Ruby on Rails, Facebook login button - given url is not permitted error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I've been trying for a long time now to get this working, without success. In my oauth.yml file the app_id and secret_id match my Facebook app settings. I've rebooted my server just in case there's outstanding configuration issues. What could be the problem?

I keep getting:

```
Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains
```

Here's a screenshot of my Facebook App settings:
[image]

My fb.init.html.erb file looks like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // console.log("fbinit file");
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<%= OAUTH_CONFIG['facebook']['app_id'] %>',
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      oauth      : true
    });
  };
  (function(d){
    // console.log("fbinit file2");
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can perform login - due to your configuration - only on populisto.com domain. Are you trying to do it on localhost?

Comment: In fact, when I run my app with rails s, I can log in fine in localhost, with the Facebook login. It's just at populisto.com where the problem is. The site is being built at present with a 'Coming soon' message, at populisto.com. The login page is actually at populisto.com/login. Could that be an issue?

Comment: No, only the domain is important. What's the callback url you supplied to facebook?

Comment: You mean in the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section, then "Website with Facebook Login", and in the 'Site URL' field? I have http://populisto.com/. (this comment is leaving out the http part but you can see it in the screenshot in my question)

Comment: Yes, I do use devise.

Comment: You're calling fb with app id `378201315578308` which is different that what you have in screenshot!

Comment: Where did you see that information?

Comment: When I click on the fb login button on you page - the url in popup window with error.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help. In my config/oauth.yml I have development, staging and production settings. The app_id and secret_id for Facebook App match those in production. Surely that is the one my app should be using? It currently matches my Staging setting. Although I see 'test: <<: *staging' which maybe sets it as default? (sorry, didn't make it originally)  I will play around with it a bit more and hopefully solve it. Please put your comments in an answer and I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like your app id provided in a screenshot and one that actually gets passed to Facebook differ.

In screenshot it starts with `144574...` and your request is

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&domain=populisto.com&scope=email&e2e=%7B%7D&app_id=378201315578308&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&client_id=378201315578308&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D25%23cb%3Df1f01bac64%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpopulisto.com%252Ff27e5c37e8%26domain%3Dpopulisto.com%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df25e63bce&origin=1&response_type=token%2Csigned_request
```

so the app_id is `378201315578308`

Comment: I've given more details to my solution below but I'd never have found it without this important contribution from the above user.

Answer (score 0):

In my oauth.yml I had:

```
development:
  facebook:  
    app_id: "3032327...etc"
    app_secret: "ebe99065439676ed...etc"
    options:
      scope: "email"
      display: "page"

staging: &staging
  facebook:
    app_id: "3782013...etc"
    app_secret: "4dabe290bd8ad7f815c54ad...etc"
    options:
      scope: "email"
      display: "page"

test:
  <<: *staging

production:
  facebook:
    app_id: "144574445...etc"
    app_secret: "501bf4e3202cd8578e322...etc"
```

So I changed all the environments to the same like so:

```
development:
  facebook:
    app_id: "14457444574...etc"
    app_secret: "501bf4e3202cd8578e322...etc"
    options:
      scope: "email"
      display: "page"

staging: &staging
  facebook:
    app_id: "1445744457...etc"
    app_secret: "501bf4e3202cd8578e3223...etc"
    options:
      scope: "email"
      display: "page"

test:
  <<: *staging

production:
  facebook:
    app_id: "1445744457...etc"
    app_secret: "501bf4e3202cd8578e3223...etc"
```

And now it works. Why is it using my 'staging' settings? Where can I change this to 'production'?

Comment: Not sure yet as not tested it, but I think I can change to production in my config/deploy.rb file: set :default_stage, "staging"